# Exception retry attempts are higher than expected

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, exception

I'm counting my Exceptions for a basic test application.  I'm expecting exceptions, we are testing the application's behavior during SQL High Availability failovers.  There is a blink period while the server fails over where some exceptions are expected, briefly.  I have some basic retry logic in my catch to count and handle/ retry the action that had the exceptions.  Here is my code.

My retry class:

```
public static class Retry
{
    public static void DoWithRetry(Action action, TimeSpan sleepPeriod, int retryCount = 3)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                action();
                break; // success!
            }
            catch
            {
                if (--retryCount == 0) throw;
                else Thread.Sleep(sleepPeriod);
            }
        }
    }


}
```

Here is where I'm referencing it in my catch:

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
    ExCounter++;
    Retry.DoWithRetry(DbInsertTestTable, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), retryCount: 3);
    //AppCount.Text = ex.Message;
}
```

The retry works but my exception count seems off as I'm getting over 100. If I turn off the retry I only get an avg of about 5 exceptions.  With the retry logic I'm expecting it to retry the action after a 1 second timespan sleep with a maximum of 3 attempts.  How am I getting over 100 exceptions?  Is there a postback here that is resetting my timespan or retry count?

Comment: sorry something happned when this posted it didn't post my question originally at the bottom of the post.  I just updated the original post so it includes my question now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I thought Timespan wasn't being passed correctly but I was wrong.  I needed to break the initial SQL insert into it's own method.  The problem was my retry which is a try catch was retrying an action() that had the original try/catch in it.  This was causing a loop of sorts in try catches which is why I had so many exceptions.  I separated the insert itself into a method and then referenced that in first try, if there's an exception, it's gets sent to my retry which uses that same SQL method (instead of using that same SQL insert with Try/Catch).  Here is what it looks like now.

```
private void DbInsertTestTable()
{

    string User = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name.ToString();
    string ServName = "";
    string SqlStatement = "INSERT INTO [myDB].[dbo].[mytable] ([AppCounterData],[User],[DateTime],[ServName]) VALUES (@COLUMN1,@COLUMN2,@COLUMN3,@@ServerName);";

    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webconfconstringname"].ConnectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = SqlCmdQuery(c, SqlStatement);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMN1", AppCounter);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMN2", User);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMN3", DateTime.Now);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@COLUMN4", ServName);
        SqlCmdOpExCl(c, cmd);
    }
}


private void SqlInsertFirstAttempt()
{
    try
    {
        DbInsertTestTable();
    }
    catch (SqlException sqlEx)
    {
        DoWithRetry(DbInsertTestTable, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), retryCount: 30);
    }           
 }
```

Still pretty new to the game.  I'm open to comments but this code is working as it should.  My exception count is normal and my retries are decrementing.